# If $f$ is continuous and $\int_a^b[f(x)]^2=0$ prove that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Intuitively, I know $[f(x)]^2\ge0$ so the integral would be the area above the x-axis and it would result in $[f(x)]^2=0$ and then $f(x)=0$.

How do I prove this with proper terms. This is a reimann integral.

Comment: Is $f $ continuous ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your assumptions on $f$. This isn't true unless you add some conditions. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes it is continuous, I just edited my problem

Comment: If $f$ is not $0$ (say $f(c)\neq 0$ where $c\in (a,b)$), then there is a $\varepsilon >0$ small s.t.  $|f(x)|^2\geq \ell>0$ on $[c-\varepsilon ,c+\varepsilon ]$. Contradiction.  If $f(a)\neq 0$ or $f(b)\neq 0$ the proof goes the same.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F:[a,b]\to[0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function with $\int_a^bF(x)dx=0$.

Assume, by the way of contradiction, that $\exists x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $F(x_0)>0$. WLOG, we can assume that $x_o\ne a,b$. By continuyity, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $F(x)>F(x_0)/2$ for every $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.

Hence, $$\int_a^bF(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}F(x)dx>\delta\cdot F(x_0)>0,$$ which is a contradiction.

Now, for your case, if $f$ is continuous, take $F=f^2$ which is continuous an positive.

If $x_0=a$, then you'll tske the interval were the function is bigger than $F(x_0)/2$ of the form $[a,a+\delta)$; If $x_0=b$, then take the interval of the form $(b-\delta,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Assume there exist $c\in[a,b]$ such that
$$f^2(c)>0$$
with $\epsilon=\frac{f^2(c)}{2}$, and
by continuity at $c$, there exist $\eta>0$ such that

$$\forall x\in[a,b]\cap ]c-\eta,c+\eta[ $$
$$\;\; \frac{f^2(c)}{2}<f^2(x)<\frac{3f^2(c)}{2}$$

now observe that

$$0=\int_a^bf^2(t)dt\ge \int_{c-\eta}^{c+\eta}f^2(t)dt$$
$$>2\eta\frac{f^2(c)}{2}>0$$

this is a contradiction.